# Differentiate multiple input form inside forEach statement

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have an array of String, the length is variable. I need to create for each String two buttons: **buy** and **remove**. They manage the quantity of the correspondent element. Like this:
[Resoult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s6Q8.png).
I tried this, works but it's not clear.

```
String go = request.getParameter("go");
if ((go != null)){
    String[] info = go.split(",");
    int index = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
if (info[0].equals("+")) {
    ++quantita[index];
} else {
    --quantita[index];
}}
```

...

```
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${length-1}" >
        <%
            int i = (int) pageContext.getAttribute("i");
            out.print(products[i] + " (" + quantita[i] +" in cart)");
        %>
        <input type=submit name="go" value="-,${i}"/>
        <input type=submit name="go" value="+,${i}"/><br>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: So you need alternative way to do above ?

Comment: Yes, i used a ploy to solve the problem but the code isn't clear. I need to pass multiple parameters with one input form: id and act. I tried to use hidden input form but i don't know how put it inside forEach without conflicts.

Comment: try to use `<table>` so under your loop you will have mutliple <tr> tag and then put your button and form inside that .ie : `<table>//your loop <tr><td>//button and form</td></tr>//loop close</table>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<button type="submit">` instead of `<input type="submit">`. This HTML element allows you to set content via children rather than via `value` attribute. This way you can simply use the `name` attribute to indicate the action and the `value` attribute  to indicate the identifier.

```
<button type=submit name="decrease" value="${i}">-</button>
<button type=submit name="increase" value="${i}">+</button>
```

```
String decrease = request.getParameter("decrease");
String increase = request.getParameter("increase");

if (decrease != null) {
    --quantity[Integer.parseInt(decrease)];
}
else if (increase != null) {
    ++quantity[Integer.parseInt(increase)];
}
```

Is that clearer?